# Infinite collection view with swiping both sides in Android

Tags: android, collectionview

I searched for that solution, but I didn't find something interesting. What I am trying to achieve is to create collection view, for example some grid which user is able to scroll horizontally and vertically or diagonally.

**QUESTION**

- Is any created library which supports such solution? If not, what would look like such solution?

Generally, it should look like grid layout:

[image: Example]

Comment: https://github.com/edgarmoises/DragDropRecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

> some grid which user is able to scroll horizontally and vertically
>
> ...
>
> Is any created library which supports such solution? If not, what would look like such solution?

I think you can use `StaticGridLayoutManager` or `DynamicGridLayoutManager` from

[recyclerview-playground](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground)

`StaticGridLayoutManager` - 2D scrolling grid with variable column count based on data set. Window of visible (non-recycled) views is determined statically.

`DynamicGridLayoutManager` - 2D scrolling grid where window of visible views is determined dynamically. Results in fewer views in memory, but scrolling performance is questionable.

for better understanding you can read these articles:

[Building a RecyclerView LayoutManager – Part 1](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/building-a-recyclerview-layoutmanager-part-1/)

[Building a RecyclerView LayoutManager – Part 2](http://www.wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/recyclerview-layoutmanager-2/)

[Building a RecyclerView LayoutManager – Part 3](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2015/02/recyclerview-layoutmanager-3/)